# Is there a way to deploy new code with Tornado/Python without restarting the server?

Tags: python, tornado

I've recently started to experiment with Python and Tornado web server/framework for web development.  Previously, I have used PHP with my own framework on a LAMP stack.  With PHP, deploying updated code/new code is as easy as uploading it to the server because of the way mod_php and Apache interact.

When I add new code or update code in Python/Tornado, do I need to restart the Tornado server?  I could see this being problematic if you have a number of active users.

(a) Do I have to restart the server, or is there another/better way?

(b) If so, how can I avoid users being disconnected/getting errors/etc. while it's restarting (which could take a few seconds)?

[One possible thought is to use the page flipping paradigm with Nginx pointing to a server, launch the new server instance with updated code, redirect Nginx there and take down the original server...?]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears the best method is to use Nginx with multiple Tornado instances as I alluded to in my original question and as Cole mentions.  Nginx can reload its configuration file on the fly .  So the process looks like this:

1. Update Python/Tornado web application code
2. Start a new instance of the application on a different port
3. Update the configuration file of Nginx to point to the new instance (testing the syntax of the configuration file first)
4. Reload the Nginx configuration file with a `kill -HUP` command
5. Stop the old instance of Python/Tornado web server

A couple useful resources on Nginx regarding hot-swapping the configuration file:

https://calomel.org/nginx.html (in "Explaining the directives in nginx.conf" section)
http://wiki.nginx.org/CommandLine (in "Loading a New Configuration Using Signals" section)

Answer (score 1):

Use [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) or [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/) and proxy to multiple Tornado processes, which you can then restart one by one. The [Tornado docs cover Nginx](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/overview.html#running-tornado-in-production), but it doesn't support websockets, so if you're using them you'll need HAProxy.

Comment: So, for example, if I have Nginx reverse proxying to four instances of Tornado and I need to update the code base... I would reboot each instance one by one.  Are you suggesting then that a user would have a 1 in 4 chance of getting a "bad gateway" error if Nginx tries to send them to a server that's down, or is there a way to modify which servers Nginx points to (without rebooting Nginx)?  Thanks!

Comment: You can remove a server from the config file, reload the Nginx config, restart it, then add it back in. Theoretically, you won't lose any requests. Edit: appears you already found this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a debug=True switch with the tornado web instance.

```
T_APP = tornado.web.Application(<URL_MAP>, debug=True)
```

This reflects the handler changes as and when they happen.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are searching for?

A module to automatically restart the server when a module is modified.
http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.4/autoreload.html

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to deploy new code with tornado/python during development without restarting the server, you can use the `realtimefunc` decorator in [this](https://github.com/Graywd/realtimefunc) GitHub repository.