# Manually reload tornado

Tags: python, reload, tornado

I don't want to run tornado in debug mode or use `autoreload` , still I want to be able to reload the server by a trigger , like requesting a specific url, or with a timer or something,

Is there a way to manually reload a tornado httpserver without killing the process and starting it again?

Comment: How would this work? Autoreload just kills the process and launches a new one. I can't get a call to tornado.autoreload._reload() to play nice, but even if you did, it would drop all open connections...

Comment: So basically this is a limitation not specific to tornado, you can't do this with any running python code, right?

Comment: Actually, I was wrong, this *should* be possible with reload: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=reload#reload

Comment: However, implementation (with reload) is...complex. Things like reload order are important. That's why Tornado just restarts the process. E.g., for mod in sys.modules.values(): reload(mod) breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I have done this is to run it behind a Nginx proxy and then restart each running process through supervisord. It's kind of clunky, but once you script it out it's not that bad actually and should be transparent to the user.

Just did a search and found a very similar but better worded answer: 
[Is there a way to deploy new code with Tornado/Python without restarting the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086885/is-there-a-way-to-deploy-new-code-with-tornado-python-without-restarting-the-ser)

Comment: So basically the answer no, I though there should be a way to load the autoreload module but call the _reload or _restart or whatever it is called manually.

Comment: There was a patch that looked at template timestamps using `os.stat` a while back that worked, but again only for templates. I am not sure of any patch that allows hot reloading of code though besides through debug. There may be a way to expose the `autoreload` to do some at some kind of event, but I have done it via the Nginx and restarting processes in turn to update their code bases on live.